# Why can't I use the Deref trait inside Drop in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits, dereference, drop

I implemented the `Deref` trait for the `MyString` struct which allows me to use an object of type `MyString` via `*o` or `o.deref()`.

But when I implement the `Drop` trait for `MyString` then the already implemented `Deref` trait cannot be used inside the `Drop` trait. Why?

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::ops::DerefMut;

struct MyString {
    s: String,
}

impl Deref for MyString {
    type Target = String;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.s
    }
}

impl DerefMut for MyString {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        &mut self.s
    }
}

impl Drop for MyString {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // println!("string dropped: {}", *self); // `MyString` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
        // println!("string dropped: {}", self.deref()); // `main::MyString` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`

        println!("string dropped: {}", self.s); // works
    }
}
let s1 = MyString {
    s: "abc".to_string(),
};
println!("s1: {}", *s1);
println!("s1: {}", s1.deref());
```

Comment: You can and you are but, but you are calling it on a `&mut MyString` which will deref to `MyString`. You should try `&**self` instead (first derefing the `&mut` _then_ derefing the `MyString`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `self` in deref is a reference, you need to dereference twice:

```rust
println!("string dropped: {}", **self);
println!("string dropped: {}", self.deref().deref());
```